# Expression 'classLevel' of type 'Any' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following class:

```
class Test {
    val classLevel = object {
        operator fun invoke() = println("test class level property invocaton")
    }

    fun foo() {
        val functionLevel = object {
            operator fun invoke() = println("test invocation")
        }
        functionLevel() // no problem
        classLevel() // Expression 'classLevel' of type 'Any' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
    }
}
```

Why does the second invoke, the one to the class property, not compile? It is declared the same way as in the function.

Comment: strange issue. I made it `private` and it worked: `private var classLevel = object { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about types.

The `classLevel` field is of an anonymous type (a subtype of `Any`, created by the object expression).  That type has an `invoke()` method.

However, that type isn't visible outside the class.  So if the property has a getter (i.e. it isn't private), the getter can't return the anonymous type; it has to return the closest named type, which is `Any`.  And `Any` doesn't have an `invoke()` method.

I'm not certain whether the code within the class will use the getter method if available, or whether the underlying field's type must exactly match that of the getter if present.  But either way, the upshot is clearly that if there's a getter, referring to `classLevel` within the class gets you an `Any` reference, and so you can't call `invoke()` on it.  (And you can't down-cast the reference to your object type, which does have `invoke()`, because that type doesn't have a name.)

One solution, as you found, is to make the field private; that removes the getter, and allows its underlying type to be the actual object type, which is why `invoke()` is then available to be called.

Another would probably be to define a named type for the object to implement.